# Unix networked printer prints multiple copies

Tags: unix, printer, hp-ux

We have a networked printer that is connected to a HP-UX Unix server. We switched identical printers and setup the new one with the same IP as the old. Users can print from Windows fine to the printer. When a user tries printing from Unix to the printer, they get six copies of the same file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a strange setting that makes the printer print multiple copies.

Answer (score 0):

Mismatch between printer firmware version and Unix driver?